# Mongoose: in an array of objects expecting custom property named id but getting also default _id

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a schema like the following:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    // Other properties here

    userMaterials: [{ title: String, category: String, id: String }]
});
```

The user should publish a material and each material is added to the userMaterial array.

The material is an object and looks like this:

```
let material = {
    id: dbMaterial.id.toString(),
    title: dbMaterial.title,
    category: req.body.category
};
```

After saving twice (just for testing what will happen) the same material object, what I found in the db is an additional _id.

```
userMaterials:
   [ { _id: 59105a5810400d7cde1d8e50,
       category: 'want-to-watch',
       title: 'jQuery Fundamentals',
       id: 590f7826f55f2e2814d113f8 },
     { _id: 59105df83369cd7fa49c9ac1,
       category: 'want-to-watch',
       title: 'jQuery Fundamentals',
       id: 590f7826f55f2e2814d113f8 } ]
```

I didn't expect that extra **_id field**, the object inside the array is not a child schema or something.. Btw when the schema is changed to userMaterials: [] it is all fine and I get what I expect actually - non-modified material object pushed into the array.

So can you explain what makes mongoose create the _id field ??

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the `_id` is added for querying subdocuments. If you want to disable the automatic creation of `_id` inside array's, you can add `_id: false`. Your updated schema will look like this:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    // Other properties here

    userMaterials: [{ title: String, category: String, id: String, _id: false }]
});
```

See the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id) about `_id` if you want to know more.